# Using form.ShowDialog() after this.Dispose();

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm launching a form from another form. I want the parent form to be disposed before showing the subform, so I use:

```
 this.Dispose();
 form.ShowDialog();
```

The form is displayed, is this the correct way to do it? The form from is launched by a call to `ShowDialog()` from the main form. I want these forms to be closed before the main form is editable.

```
EDIT:
```

This is the Basic Process

**Mainform>(Showdialog)>form1>(dispose+showDialog)>form2(dispose)>Mainform**

Comment: this.Hide(); form.showDialog();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to ensure the parent is not visible before the child is shown, AND you want the parent to Close:

```
var f = new ChildForm();
this.Hide();
f.Show();
this.Close();
```

`ShowDialog()` means, "display this form and *return to me* after it's closed". That is not what you described you want to happen.

Based on your comment, it might make more sense to create and show form2 from your main form.

In the main form:

```
   DialogResult form1Result;
     using (var f = new Form1())
     {
        form1Result = f.ShowDialog();
     }
     if (form1Result == DialogResult.OK)
     {
        using (var f2 = new Form2())
        {
           f2.ShowDialog();
        }
     }
```

And in Form1 event where you originally spawned Form2

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
this.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks.My approach works fine without any problems,is there a need for this additional code.

Comment: The *intent* of your code isn't reflected by the methods you chose. Yes, it may work, but when you read `ShowDialog()` there's a certain expectation of behavior.  The other two lines of code aren't going to affect performance in any way.

Comment: Mainform>(Showdialog)>form1>(dipose+showDialog)>form2(dipose)>Mainform

Comment: Perhaps you should show form2 after closing form1 and setting an appropriate DialogResult.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `Dispose` on any object (including the current object known as `this`) is saying you have finished with that object, it is terminally finished with.

Better to `Close` the first dialogue and then show the second one.

Comment: Please give an Example.Will the resources be freed if i use close.

Comment: @techno Probably not, it depends on details you have not given. On further thought you would probably be better refactoring your code to have a controlling component that shows the first form and then the second. It can then dispose the first form when it is closed.

Comment: The 'Close' approach is not working the old form is not closed it is present in the background

Comment: @techno Then something else is going on. But I suspect your problem is using a form after its normal lifecycle – being closed – and thus easy to break assumptions built into WinForms. In particular `ShowDialog` returns when the dialog is closed.

Comment: @techno WinForms `Form` instances have a life-cycle. This ends with the calling of its Close method (perhaps from the GUI, perhaps from code). At this point the Form is no longer viable for anything other than extracting data. You are trying to perform further GUI operations: breaking the assumptions of that life-cycle.

Answer (score 1):

If you are showing the child dialog modally (which you are in this case) then you can hide the parent dialog What you can do is hide the parent form, show the child form, and then close the parent form.

```
var form = new SomeForm();
this.Hide();
form.ShowDialog(); // the code will be blocked at this point until the child form closes
this.Close();
this.Dispose(); // i'm not sure if this is necessary anymore. check MSDN
```

If you are showing a form (not modally), you can hide the parent form, and listen to the child form's close event and then close the parent form in the handler

```
void childFormClosed(Event e) 
{
    this.Close();
}

var form = new SomeForm();
form.Closed += new EventHandler... // I usually rely on intellisense with this
this.Hide();
form.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Its good but in the first case there is no need for this.Close();

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to call Dispose manually. I usually prefer Close and let the framework invoke Dispose automatically.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I think you cant do that, because when you call ShowDialog method, the child form becomes dependent on its parent form. so the call of dispose will be suspended until you finish with the child form.

I think you have to call the "Show" method and after that you can call the dispose method.

Comment: I created 2 form2 and added this code : 
Form3 f = new Form3();
this.Dispose();
f.Show();
and it works fine, maybe there is other problems in your app, what happens when you run your app ?

Answer (score 0):

The lifecycle of the child form is depends on its parent lifecycle, that means, once you invoke the parent.close of the parent form, it will dispose all objects created by that instance.

You have to create the child independently from the parent.